# Instagram explore/tags API doesn't return JSON data

Tags: c#, json, api, instagram, hashtag

The last few days, Instagram hashtag query string "explore/tags/hashtag_Name/?__a=1" started to not return "JSON" data.

For example when I send web request at the beginning two or three times I get JSON data but then for other requests I always get some html file code with title login-Instagram. I don't know if there are some changes with Instagram API some limitation for requests.

Anyone who has same problem who can help me?

So here is my code:

```
public Task<T> GetInstaHashtags(string search_Hashtag){
WebRequest instaHashtag = WebRequest.Create("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"+ search_Hashtag + "/?__a=1";
instaHashtag.Method = "GET";
instaHashtag.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType]="application/json";
string response = null;
using(var getResponse = instaHashtag.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()){
      var headerResponse = new StreamReader(getResponse);
      response = headerResponse.ReadToEnd();
}
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
return result;
}
```